# C++ Can't access dynamically allocated array of cards after construction

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic

this one's been bugging me for a while now. The project is to be a card game.

I initially created the deck and moved on, but had to come back and change it because I'd done it wrong. 
The `shuffle()` method works just fine if its called from anywhere within the deck.cpp, but if I create a Deck* deck; in the hand.cpp file, then call deck->shuffle() it hangs and eventually crashes.
I think it's something to do with the dynamic allocation of the `Card* deckOfCards`

The console output from the code below is:

```
Shuffle Called
Shuffle Successful
Destructor Called
Shuffle Called
```

Then it just hangs and crashes.
I've tried remove the destructor, but that didn't help...

Is anyone able to shed some light on what's going amiss here? Any suggestions would be very much appreciated! See code below.

hand.h

```
#ifndef _hand_h
#define _hand_h

#include "deck.h"

/// COMMENTS HERE
class Hand {
public:
    ///Constructors / Destructors
    Hand();
    ~Hand();

    Deck* deck;
    ///Accessors

    ///Mutators
    void clear();
    void addCard(Card*);
    std::string makeBid();

    ///Operators
    friend std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& out, Hand& hand);

private:

    int highCardPoints;
    int lengthPoints;
    bool balancedHand;

protected:
};

#endif // _hand_h
```

hand.cpp

```
/**
 * The Hand class is responsible for, among other things, storing the cards dealt to a      * particular player.
 */
#include <vector>

#include "hand.h"

std::vector<Card*> suitClubs;
std::vector<Card*> suitDiamonds;
std::vector<Card*> suitHearts;
std::vector<Card*> suitSpades;

///Constructors / Destructors
Hand::Hand(){

    Deck();
    deck->shuffle();
}

Hand::~Hand(){
}

///Mutators
void Hand::clear(){

}
```

deck.h

```
#ifndef _deck_h
#define _deck_h

#include "card.h"
#include <iostream>
/**
 * Declare unchanging numbers that relate to the number of ranks and suits possible
 * Prevents use of magic numbers while iterating for creation of all cards
 */
const static int RANKS = 13;
const static int SUITS = 4;
const static int DECK_SIZE = RANKS * SUITS;

class Deck{
public:

    ///Constructors / Destructors
    Deck();
    ~Deck();

    Card* deckOfCards[DECK_SIZE + 1];
    //Card **deckOfCards;
    Card* tempCard;


    ///Accessors


    ///Mutators
    void reset(); ///Sets cardsDealt to 0;
    Card* dealNextCard(); ///Gets the next card from the deck
    void shuffle(); ///Shuffles the cards in the deck

    friend ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, Deck&); ///Sends a string representation of the cards in the deck to the output stream.
    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream&, Deck&);


private:
    int deckIndex, cardsDealt;
    int tempCardIndex = DECK_SIZE + 1;

protected:

};

#endif // _deck_h
```

deck.cpp

```
#include "deck.h"
#include "random.h"

#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

Random randomizer;


///Noarg constructor – Creates a dynamic array of Card objects and initialises them. Initialises cardsDealt to 0.
Deck::Deck(){
    *deckOfCards = new Card[DECK_SIZE];
    tempCard = new Card();
    cardsDealt, deckIndex = 0;

    ///Iterate through suits
    for (int suitIterator = 0; suitIterator < SUITS; suitIterator++){

        ///Iterate through all possible ranks for each suit
        for (int rankIterator = 0; rankIterator < RANKS; rankIterator++){
            ///Dynamically create a new card for each rank and suit at the top of the deck
            deckOfCards[deckIndex] = new Card(static_cast<Rank>(rankIterator), static_cast<Suit>(suitIterator));

        //cout << deckOfCards[deckIndex]->toString() << endl;
            deckIndex++;
        }
    }

    shuffle();
}


Deck::~Deck(){
    delete [] deckOfCards;
    delete [] tempCard;
    cout << "Destructor called" << endl;
} ///Destructor - deletes the dynamic allocations

///Sets cardsDealt back to zero
void Deck::reset(){
    cardsDealt = 0;
}

///Returns a pointer to the next Card object from the deck, increments cardsDealt
Card* Deck::dealNextCard(){
    *tempCard = *deckOfCards[cardsDealt];
    cardsDealt++;
    return tempCard;
}

///Shuffles all cards in the deck
void Deck::shuffle(){

    cout << "Shuffle called" << endl;
    int shuffleIndex = 0;
    ///Reset shuffleIndex back to zero just in case it's accessed before the program finishes and still holds a value
    /// Iterate through and shuffle all cards
    /// Algorithm: For each iteration, pick a random card in the deck, swap card at iterated index with randomly chosen card
    for (int i = 0; i < DECK_SIZE; i++){
        shuffleIndex = randomizer.randomInteger(0, (DECK_SIZE - 1));

        *deckOfCards[tempCardIndex] = *deckOfCards[shuffleIndex];
        *tempCard = *deckOfCards[shuffleIndex];

        deckOfCards[shuffleIndex] = deckOfCards[i];
        *deckOfCards[i] = *tempCard;
    }
    cout << "Shuffle successful" << endl;
}
```

The Card object has attributes RANK and SUIT. I can provide those if needed as well.

Comment: Please do not edit *answers* into the *question*. The question should remain a question. The answers appear below it. If you'd like, you can post your own answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Hand::deck` is a pointer that is never initialized. The call `Deck();` in your `Hand` constructor creates an anonymous instance of `Deck` that is immediately destroyed again while `deck` still points to nothing. Try `deck=new Deck;` instead of `Deck();`

Comment: I think that does fix something, but now it's hanging after the first "Shuffle called"

EDIT: That does fix it, marking it as answer. This error must be my shuffling method. I'll post back with answer once that's fixed too. 
Thanks!

Comment: `tempCardIndex =  DECK_SIZE+1` points beyond the last element of `deckOfCards`, which is `deckOfCards[DECK_SIZE]` (indices start at 0). Also, you should use `delete tempCard;` in the destructor (no `[]`)

Comment: Wow you found it before I was finished updating the post, thanks!
I originally had it as `Card* tempCard`, but changed it to sit at the end of the deck thinking that would fix my problem. I'll go back to using as its own `Card*`

Comment: Is there a way I can highlight rows in the above code to make it obvious what I changed to fix it? Still kinda new to Stack's formatting

Comment: I'm relatively new myself, but I would say don't sweat it. I think the answer and our comments are sufficient for anyone who's interested, and most people jump to the answer first anyway.

Comment: Awesome, I've commented it as best I can. Thanks again Roberto, you have no idea how happy you've just made me :)